# bounce mail handler not receiving notifications

Tags: php, google-app-engine

My app has 3 modules. frontend, tasker & invoicer. Invoicer generates pdf invoices and emails them to customers on a daily cron task.  Before I set-up the task I want to verify that I'm able to receive bounced emails. So, I did a test by sending a dummy email to a non-existent email address and was expecting to receive a notification on the handler I've set up, but I have not received this 24hr after. Logs Viewer shows no records for _ah/bounce at all.

I have in invoicer.yaml the following:

```
inbound_services:
- mail_bounce

handlers:    
- url: /_ah/bounce
  script: bounced_emails_handler.php
  login: admin
```

The email I set this to be sent from is invoicer@"app-id".appspotmail.com.

Comment: I've changed the bounce handler to be on default module and it works as expected now.  Apparently, '/_ah/bounce' is not dispatchable. so moving bounced_emails_handler.php to frontend module solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed the bounce handler to be on default module and it works as expected now. Apparently, '/_ah/bounce' is not dispatchable. so moving bounced_emails_handler.php to frontend module solved it.

- Just posting my comment as an answer, so this can be marked answered.